# sql: afficher Les articles sans aucune vente en 2010

Tags: sql

My tables:

sinvoiced

| num_facture | ITEM_REF | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2010-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | b | 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | c | 2012-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | d | 2013-01-31 00:00:00.000 |

itmsales

| ITEM_REF |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f |

sql: display Items without any sales in 2010

I want to display items without any sale in 2010

Comment: Hello. Stackoverflow.com is an English-only site. Please make sure that if you ask a question here or post an answer, that you do so in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translated as following.

sql: display Items without any sales in 2010

I want to display item without any sale in 2010

```sql
select ITEM_REF
from   itmsales 
where  ITEM_REF not in 
(select ITEM_REF 
from    sinvoiced 
where   date between '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2010-12-31 23:59:59.999');
```